# How does one allow administrator access to folder-redirected user folders?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, folder-redirection

There appear to be two steps to be followed if one wishes to allow Administrators to have access to User Folders that reside on the server through Folder Redirection:

1. Set up permissions on the shared folders
2. Set up the GPO

[KB288991](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288991) gives details for doing so on Windows Server 2003. These instructions do not, however, seem to fit Windows Server 2012 Essentials. In particular, when following the instructions on setting permissions, part 5 poses problems, which instructs one to do the following:

> [...] clear the **Allow inheritable permissions from the parent to propagate
>   to this object and all child objects. Include these with entries
>   explicitly defined here**. check box.

On Windows Server 2012, there appears to be no such check box. What is the equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Advanced Security Settings* dialog near the bottom you will see the **Disable Inheritance** button. Click it to stop the folder from inheriting permissions:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. The button currently reads "Enable inheritance", so I presume I can simply leave it as it is. Can I also ignore the _Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object_ check box? The folder is currently empty.

Comment: That would be correct.